# Why postman form-data return empty request when uploading file to laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, file-upload, postman

Why postman form-data methode return empty request when uploading file to laravel ?

Hello, I trying to send an image to laravel server using postman form-data but the image does not exist in the request and the request is totally empty

this is my controller :

[image]

i'm totally blocked here !!

Comment: Show your postman request

Comment: Check `dd($request->all());`

Answer (score 1):

send the request as such :

[image]

And it will work

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I was using PUT method then i replace it with POST and it did work perfectlly